# hadoop new version - HDP-2.6.3.0 failed because unnecessary repo file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, redhat, ambari

we are trying to install the new hadoop version HDP version as scratch installation on our redhat machines ( redhat 7.3 version)

```
HDP-2.6.3.0-centos7-rpm.tar.gz
ambari-2.6.0.0-centos7.tar.gz
```

before installing the new HDP version , our current HDP repository is ( under /etc/yum.repo.d )

so regarding that we have already exising HDP reposoitory , we asume that hadoop installation will use this repo for installation

example of out HDP repo ( master02 is the ambari server machine )

```
more HDP.repo
[HDP-2.6]
name=HDP-2.6
baseurl=http://master02.sys56.com/HDP/centos7/2.6.3.0-235

path=/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

but during HDP-2.6.3.0 installation ( blueprint installation ) , we saw very strange thing.....

in spite we already have HDP repository

blueprint installation push another repo file: ( under /etc/yum.rep.d )

as the following:

```
more ambari-hdp-1.repo ( this repo not created on the previos version )

[HDP-2.6-repo-1]
name=HDP-2.6-repo-1
baseurl=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/2.x/updates/2.6.0.3


path=/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
[HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21-repo-1]
name=HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21-repo-1
baseurl=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21/repos/centos7


path=/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

**the question is why ?**

I ask this because this new repo corrupted the blueprint installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR;**

You need to change the repository information in your `hdp.repo` file to match that of the new Ambari file before installing your packages. You can keep your custom baseurl but the repository id needs to match the new file.

**Long Version:**

There is an inconsistency between Ambari Blueprint and the Hortonworks repository files. Ambari Blueprint is using the following file to set up it's repositories: http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.3.0/HDP-2.6.3.0-235.xml

`$ curl -sS http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.3.0/HDP-2.6.3.0-235.xml | grep "repoid"
        <repoid>HDP-2.6</repoid>
        <repoid>HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21</repoid>`

Ambari automatically adds `-repo-1` to the repoid before looking for the repositories on the target systems so we get:

- HDP-2.6-repo-1
- HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21-repo-1

Hortonworks offer their own yum repo file here: http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.3.0/hdp.repo
but the repository IDs are different:

`$ curl -sS http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.3.0/hdp.repo | grep "[][]"
[HDP-2.6.3.0]
[HDP-UTILS-1.1.0.21]`

If Ambari does not find the repository (which it doesn't because the IDs are different) then it adds it's own which breaks your setup.